# exporting gnosis transactions to csv for tax

Tags: gnosis-safe

I need to export my gnosis transactions for tax but I can't get it to work.
I've used this from teh Gnosis support (2) Fetch the data in JSON from the Safe transaction service
The Gnosis Safe transaction service indexes all Gnosis Safe transactions.
There is an endpoint that can be used to return those transactions in a JSON format:
Make sure to use a checksummed Safe address in the URL. For the Gnosis Safe address 0xA063Cb7CFd8E57c30c788A0572CBbf2129ae56B6, the URL would be https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/0xA063Cb7CFd8E57c30c788A0572CBbf2129ae56B6/multisig-transactions/.
it produces a json file and I've tried to use a json csv converter but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to JSON to CSV Converter: https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm
2. Select "Enter Url" tab
3. Paste the URL: https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/0xA063Cb7CFd8E57c30c788A0572CBbf2129ae56B6/multisig-transactions/
4. Optional: Choose a suitable file name and click "Download result"
5. Here is the CSV version of the url you provided:
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pWe39Ti5EhrG3fmq0YJgKA1Kl8BwdWOXWTNZxyCEOCA/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

### JSON as CSV

[image]